# Bash script to read from a file and echo

Tags: macos, bash, shell

How would I go about reading in from a file and echoing out each line until EOF?

I have tried this:

```
FILE=/Users/<User>/Desktop/Names.txt

echo "################################"

while read p; do
        echo $p

done < $FILE
```

But when I run it, the output is this:

```
################################
{rtf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1265cocoasubrtf200
{fonttblf0fswissfcharset0 Helvetica;}
{colortbl;red255green255blue255;}
margl1440margr1440vieww10800viewh8400viewkind0
     pardtx720tx1440tx2160tx2880tx3600tx4320tx5040tx5760tx6480tx7200tx7920tx8640pardirnatural
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I go about doing this correctly?

Comment: Is that different from `cat /Users/<User>/Desktop/Names.txt`?

Comment: What is in `/Users/<User>/Desktop/Names.txt` to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this form instead:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
    echo "$p"
done < "$file"
```

- We add `IFS=` to make `IFS` unset on the instance of `read` so no word splitting splitting or trimming of spaces would occur.
- `-r` prevents backslashes to have meaning.
- Quoting variables around `""` prevents word splitting.

See [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) and [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

Another way to do it is to load your lines to an array with `readarray` or `mapfile`. This needs Bash 4.0. See [mapfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile).

```
readarray -t lines < "$file"
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: so I changed it to this: FILE=/Users/<username>/Desktop/Names.txt
echo "################################"

while IFS= read -r p; do
        echo $p
       
done < $FILE     and now I get :  ################################
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf200
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 123\
1234\
test\

Comment: Great and beautiful :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your file is not plain text. It is Rich Text Format (RTF). What you're seeing is the actual content of the file.

The fact that it has a .txt file extension and looks "normal" in an RTF-aware text editor is misleading you.

Comment: Didn't see that :) +1

Comment: How do I go about making it a pure .txt?